# ODE: $x' = x+x^2+x^3t$, $x(2)=x_0$. Find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}|_{x_0=0}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem:** $x'=x+x^2+x^3t$ and $x(2)=x_0$. Find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}|_{x_0=0}$

**My attempt:**

Multiplying both sides by $x^{-3}$ and substituting $y=x^{-2}$ gives us Riccati equation: $\frac{-1}{2}y'=y+y^{0.5}+t$. We could solve it for $y$ if we knew one solution but I couldn't came up with it.

Another try: substituting z=$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_0}$ where $y=x-x_0$ and differentiating with respect to $x_0$ gives us: $z' = (z+1)(1+2(y+x_0)+3t(y+x_0)^2)$ but how should I proceed?

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}|_{x_0=0}$?

Comment: In other words $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}(t,0)$, where $x= x(t,x_0)$.

Comment: If $x_0$ is a constant, how could you possibly use $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$

Comment: Now it's not. You can treat is as a parameter. It's easy to see if you substitute $y=x-x_0$. Then you have an ODE for $y$ with $y_0=0$ and the parameter $x_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to me that I've found a solution.

Begin with a substitution: $z=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}$. We get: $z' = z+2xz + 3tx^2z$.

Now we can observe that: $x(t)=0$ is a solution of the first equation with a condition $x(0)=0$. Then we can see that the right side of this equation is locally Lipschitz continuous hence by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem we know that it's the only solution. Hence we know that $z(2,0)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}(2,0)=1$ and we want to find the general form of $z(t,0)$ but since we know $x\equiv 0$ we can substitute it and get $z'=z \Rightarrow z= Ce^{t}$. Taking into account the initial condition: $C=e^{-2}$ gives us $z=e^{t-2} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}=z(t,0)=e^{t-2}$